# Is a strlen call in snprintf causing this segfault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strlen, printf

I have a `void *`, call it `data`, whose length I know, but is not null terminated.  I make a call like this `snprintf(line, sizeof(line), "%*s", n, (const char*)data)` where `n` is the known length.  Almost always this works, but occasionally it results in a segfault.

Whenever the segfault occurs, the back trace says the problem is inside strlen.  And when I print `data` inside gdb, I see something like this

```
(gdb) p n
$1 = 88
(gdb) p (const char*) data
$2 = 0x1d752fa8
"JASDF" ... "ADS"<Address 0x1d753000 out of bounds>
(gdb) p 0x1d753000-0x1d752fa8
$3 = 88
```

`data` is indeed 88 characters, but isn't null terminated, in fact, it seems that it lies right up against a segment.  My guess is that snprintf is always called strlen on data and I usually get lucky in that even though `data` isn't null terminated, there is a `\0` before I hit the segment and then occasionally I get unlucky and it is.  Is that right?  If so, what's the work around?

This is what the stack trace looks like

```
#0  0x0000003c8927839e in strlen () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003c89246749 in vfprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003c8926941a in vsnprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000003c8924d0a3 in snprintf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

**EDIT** To answer my own question about the work around, strncpy is a more appropriate function to call.  I used snprintf by habit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `snprintf(line, sizeof(line), "%*s", n, (const char*)data)`

`data` isn't zero terminated? Then you are doing it wrong.

```
snprintf(line, sizeof(line), "%.*s", n, (const char*)data);
```

Notice the dot.

In case of strings, the first `*` in the `*.*` if for the desired output (on screen) length - input length is the second `*`. `man printf` for more.

And obviously in the case of `%*s` formatting might call strlen(), since it needs to know whether it needs to pad the output and how to pad it.

Comment: You're right.  The man page is pretty explicit in discussing non null terminating strings and the precision modifier.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're right. There's no guarantee that `printf` won't call `strlen`, even if it doesn't necessarily have to in a given context. You're lying by providing something that isn't a C string as the parameter for an `%s` formatting specifier, and so you've broken the contract of `printf`. Undefined behavior results.

Comment: `%s` supports non-0 terminated strings: `%.*s`

Comment: The real problem is his format string is wrong, use `"%.*s"` instead of `"%*s"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you analysis is correct.  If the buffer is not null terminated, then the strlen call will read until it finds a `\0`.  If it runs past the end of the segment (and the next segment is not valid), then it will produce an exception.

The solution is to either null-terminate it or put it in another buffer that you can null terminate.

Comment: see my response below. formatting already supports non-0 terminated strings.

Answer (score 0):

The "workaround" is to use `memcpy()`:

```
size_t validlen = n < sizeof line ? n : (sizeof line - 1);
memcpy(line, data, validlen);
line[validlen] = '\0';
```

Comment: "%.*s" is the way to do it - no redundant copying required.

Comment: There is no redundant copying in my answer - there is only a *single* copy, using `memcpy()` instead of `snprintf()`.